# Odoo 11 community payroll module

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I've installed recently odoo 11 in my computer. I was trying to access the payroll module to try the salaries feature but I'm not being able to find it.

I've checked the show all features in accountant module but the part where I should put the contracts and where I could extract the pay slip is not showing up.

How can I make it available? Thanks

Comment: Did you check the user rights of our users ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched for hr_payroll in the Apps menu, without(remove it) the `Apps` filter that appears active by default in the search box?.

If you have it installed, you should see that there is a top menu named `Payroll` with the features